# semi circular volume controller using seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to design a semicircular volume controller for my application , Is it possible to use seekbar for it , if so is it possible to make it look semi circular , i searched a lot but dint find any information on this.

Comment: what is "semicircular controller"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont find something you can start with this , https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar if there is no direct option then you can try modifying the circularSeekbar.java to draw a semi-circle instead of circle , rest eveything regarding seeking and progress works fine in this class